# ListView in Fragment not showing any Items ANDROID

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to use a ListView in my Fragment which is displayed by a TabViewer2. The listadapter I used is the `ArrayAdapter<String>`. Unfourtunately the ListVIew does not show any Items. However the TextViews above and below the List are displayed properly.

fragment_log.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.main.LogFragment">
    <TextView android:text="LOGGING"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:divider="#000"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:foreground="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="DD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout >
```

LogFragment.kt

```
class LogFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = LogFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var listAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String>
    private lateinit var binding : FragmentLogBinding
    private var list = arrayOf("test1", "test2", "test3")



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding = FragmentLogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        listAdapter = ArrayAdapter(activity as Context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
        binding.listView.adapter = listAdapter

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.getLogList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            listAdapter.clear()
            listAdapter.addAll(it)
        })


        Toast.makeText(context, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please show your `Adapter` code to see the full picture.

Comment: @DanielKnauf Which one do you mean? The `ArrayAdapter` is the standard one from `` `android.widget.ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I had to make some research on `ArrayAdapter` first, because I don't know it, but from what I see the adapter should be fine. Did you try it out with initial data, e.g. `list1`. What looks strange to me is your xml because normally with filled view you do width=match_parent and height=wrap_content. Is there a reason for 100dp. Maybe you have to scroll to see the first entry? Also a reason could be that your `viewModel` is never emitting any value.